# Woocommerce show shipping fields on order-pay page IF cash on delivery (COD) was selected at checkout

Tags: woocommerce, woothemes, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

My shipping fields are deactivated at checkout because I'm using a payment gateway that asks for shipping data so I do this to avoid asking for the same shipping data twice.

I would like to SHOW the shipping fields on the order-pay page which comes right after the checkout only IF the payment gateway selected was Cash On Delivery (COD)

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!